# Filling a Matrix with "For Loop" Taking Too Long

Tags: json, r, for-loop, bigdata

I'm trying to create a data frame that is about 1,000,000 x 5 by using a for-loop, but it's been 5+ hours and I don't think it will finish very soon. I'm using the rjson library to read in the data from a large json file. Can someone help me with filling up this data frame in a faster way?

```
library(rjson)

# read in data from json file
file <- "/filename"
c <- file(file, "r")
l <- readLines(c, -1L)
data <- lapply(X=l, fromJSON)

# specify variables that i want from this data set
myvars <- c("url", "time", "userid", "hostid", "title")
newdata <- matrix(data[[1]][myvars], 1, 5, byrow=TRUE)

# here's where it goes wrong
for (i in 2:length(l)) {
newdata <- rbind(newdata, data[[i]][myvars])
}

newestdata <- data.frame(newdata)
```

Comment: You are in the Second Circle of the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: Check out the R inferno. You are growing `newdata` with each loop iteration and eating up your resources. It is better to pre-allocate memory for your 1000000 x 5 matrix and then fill in the info.

Comment: ...but the idiomatic way would be something like `do.call(rbind,data)`. And see `rbindlist` from the data.table package for something even speedier.

Comment: R is copy on change so you are exponentially increasing the time required at every loop. use `rbindlist` (from `data.table`) on a `lapply` or something similar.

Comment: `data <- sapply(X=l, fromJSON)` should do it, though you might have to transpose the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taking forever because each iteration of your loop is creating a new, bigger object. Try this:

```
slice <- function(field, data) unlist(lapply(data, `[[`, field))
data.frame(Map(slice, myvars, list(data)))
```

This will create a data.frame and preserve your original data types: character, numeric, etc.,  if it matters. While forcing everything into a matrix will coerce everything into character class.

Comment: This worked on my smaller test data set but not on my actual large data set. What's wrong here? This is the error I got. 
"Error in data.frame(buzz = c("http://www.azcentral.com/community/phoenix/articles/20121214phoenix-rabbi-family-share-faith.html",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1349674, 1339352"

Comment: Can you be more precise about "does not work"? If you get an error message, can you share? Are there records in your file that do not contain all five entries?

Comment: The error message is posted above. I got this error when I ran the line: "newdata <- data.frame(Map(slice, myvars, list(data)))". I'm not 100% sure but I do believe that each json object has at least these 5 entries at minimum. Is there a simple way to check for sure? I do know that some objects have more than 5 entries.

Comment: @user3287712 provide a small dataset using dput() or a link a dropbox file in order to get a concrete answer

Comment: can you please provide `length(data)`? I am trying to figure out if some of the entries have length == 0 or length > 1.

Comment: length(data) is 1349674

Comment: So yes, you have records with missing entries. Try replacing `slice` above with this one: `slice <- function(field, data) unlist(lapply(lapply(data, "[[", field), function(x) if (is.null(x)) NA else x))
`

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly. One more question though: I'm trying to do the same thing to another json file which is much bigger. However, this time it gets stuck on "data <- lapply(X=l, fromJSON)" for a very long time. Is there a faster way to get around this?

Comment: Not that I can think of, that would use R. I would probably use another language like Perl to read the file line by line and convert it into a 5-column csv file. If I answered your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the big tick on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Without the data, it's hard to be sure, but there are a couple of things you are doing that are relatively slow.  This should be faster, but again, without the data, I can't test:

```
newdata <- vapply(data, `[`, character(5L), myvars)
```

I'm also assuming that your `data` is `character`, which I think it has to be based on `title`.

Also, as others have noted, the reason yours is slow is because you are growing an object, which requires R to keep re-allocating memory.  `vapply` will allocate the memory ahead of time because it knows the size of each iterations result, and how many items there are.